# Using Complex types in OData queries

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm trying to sort my data by a complex type `Address` that's is on my main entity `Customer`.

```
public partial class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        this.Address = new Address();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public partial class Address
{
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
}
```

I've queried the data, and I can sort it by name using `$sort=Name`, but when I do `$sort=Address.PostCode` I get:

`"The child type 'Address.PostCode' in a cast was not an entity type. Casts can only be performed on entity types.","type":"Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataException","stacktrace":"   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.DottedIdentifierBinder.BindDottedIdentifier(DottedIdentifierToken dottedIdentifierToken, BindingState state)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.MetadataBinder.BindCast(DottedIdentifierToken dottedIdentifierToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.MetadataBinder.Bind(QueryToken token)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.OrderByBinder.ProcessSingleOrderBy(BindingState state, OrderByClause thenBy, OrderByToken orderByToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.OrderByBinder.BindOrderBy(BindingState state, IEnumerable1 orderByTokens)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.ODataUriParser.ParseOrderByImplementation(String orderBy, IEdmType elementType, IEdmEntitySet entitySet)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.OrderByQueryOption.get_OrderByClause()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.OrderByQueryOption.get_OrderByNodes()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.EnsureStableSortOrderBy(OrderByQueryOption orderBy, ODataQueryContext context)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.ApplyTo(IQueryable query, ODataQuerySettings querySettings)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.QueryableAttribute.ApplyQuery(IQueryable queryable, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.QueryableAttribute.ExecuteQuery(Object response, HttpRequestMessage request, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.QueryableAttribute.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)"`

When I do `$sort=Address/PostCode` I get:

`"Only ordering by properties at the root level is supported for non-primitive collections. Nested properties and expressions are not supported.","type":"Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataException","stacktrace":"   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.OrderByNode.CreateCollection(OrderByClause orderByClause)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.OrderByQueryOption.get_OrderByNodes()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.EnsureStableSortOrderBy(OrderByQueryOption orderBy, ODataQueryContext context)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.ApplyTo(IQueryable query, ODataQuerySettings querySettings)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.QueryableAttribute.ApplyQuery(IQueryable queryable, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.QueryableAttribute.ExecuteQuery(Object response, HttpRequestMessage request, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.QueryableAttribute.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)"`

So how do I sort it?

I'm using Entity Framework v6 and System.Web.Http.OData v5.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The syntax for $orderby on nested properties is the later i.e you should do `$orderby=Address/PostCode`.

And, we didn't have support for `$orderby` on nested properties in V2 RTM (the current bits). However, we recently [fixed](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/791) that and this feature is available in our nightly builds and would be available on nuget in our next release.

To access our nightly builds, you could follow this [link](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Use%20Nightly%20Builds) for details.